# MapFish: Display number of pages

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

I put this tag in a text block of the mainPage:

```
- !text
    text: 'Page: ${pageNum}/${pageTot}'
```

But it appears only the current page number!

Someone tell me knows how to solve this problem?